# SQL filter using 2 dates + SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset that looks like below

```
ctry | start | end
```

I have a second dataset b
that has

```
ctry | start | end
```

as well as other columns.

I would like to filter the second dataset based on ctry, start and end dates

Answer (score 1):

Am presuming you are looking for some kind of inner join (keep all records in the second dataset, b, if the three columns match those in the first dataset).  Try the following approach (one of many):

```
proc sql;
create table filtered as
  select b.*
  from first_ds as a /* you never said what your first dataset was called */
  inner join b as b
  on a.ctry=b.ctry
/* edits following OP comment */
   and a.start < b.end
   and a.end > b.start;
```

Comment: sorry wasnt very clear, you are right i want to preserve everything in b; all records in b which belong to the ctry in a between the start and end date specified for that ctry in a is what I was looking for..

Comment: the new query retains all records in B where the start / end dates in A fall within the range set by B (assuming b.start is always less than b.end)